# Can I make python's logging.getLogger return a LoggerAdapter?

Tags: python, logging

The `LoggerAdapter` class in python is used for providing contextual information to messages logged.  After subclassing it, the subclass can be used in place of a logger, and the subclass can intercept and modify/augment the message being logged.

Is it possible to make `logging.getLogger(name)` return that custom LoggerAdapter class instead of the generic logger?  It seems like the `LoggerAdapter` class would be useless if it had to be separately instantiated in every individual file it is used in, and it doesn't seem like I should have to import it, since the `logger` module seems to let you use its methods to access the loggers everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to make `logging.getLogger(name)` return custom LoggerAdapter class. `logging.getLogger` is implemented to work to return a generic logger. 
It is true that `LoggerAdapter` is useless in the scenario you described.

Though every individual file call `logging.getLogger(name)` to get their logger, you still have the chance to provide contextual information to messages.

Try this:

```
import logging
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        # suppose one of your contextual info is ip
        record.ip = custom_function_to_set_ip()
        return True

# this will be the parent logger of individual file logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
fh.addFilter(ContextFilter())
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

since fh is installed on the parent of individual file logger, a log message created by individual file logger will be handled by fh. In the handler flow,
the message can be further processed by Filter.

Please refer to https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow

Answer (score 0):

You may now use `logging.setLoggerClass(klass)`.
Trouble is still how to manage this in shared hosted environments (e.g. Flask, FastAPI, ...), but if you 'own' the env, you can alter its global props.
Also make sure that you replace only loggers for your own module...